# Rejection handler in latest ember-data (beta 1 and beta 2)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

It looks like the latest versions of ember-data removed the rejectionHandler. Here is the old code https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/4764b5d70c41c133edcbd1822bc587483c39e180/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L11-L15 and example usage https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/4764b5d70c41c133edcbd1822bc587483c39e180/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L372.

I was using this to handle 401 unauthorized status codes from my server. Can I accomplish the same thing using the latest ember-data? I know I could pass a second function to all `find` and `save` calls to handle failure. But how to do that application wide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that application-wide you should use the global error handling capabilities of the router.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    error: function(error, transition) {
      //If error was a 401, do something...
    }
  }
});
```

See [How to do cool stuff with the new Router API](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Only change I'd make is putting the `error` function in the `actions` hash. `events` hash is deprecated.

Comment: Cool glad that helped. Good point re: actions vs. events hash, updated my answer.

Comment: You know what though, this only seems to work when visiting a Route. For example, if I click a button that fires an action that calls .save() on my model, then Ember data sends a PUT request that the server returns 401 (because the session expired), this error handler is never called. If I then click a link that transitions to some route, this error handler is called. It's like I need to define the error handler for all ember-data communication too. Not sure where though

Comment: @davekaro Ever figure that out? I'm struggling with the same thing.